# How to retrieve TD value of table column (ID) which is inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater with a HTML Table layout as follows where it fills from the database dynamically,

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
        </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionId") %> <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionId") %>' runat="server" /> </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Question") %> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><asp:RadioButton ID="op1" runat="server" OnCheckedChange="check_Answer"/></td><td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer1") %> </td></tr>
                <tr><td><asp:RadioButton ID="op2" runat="server" OnCheckedChange="check_Answer"/></td><td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer2") %> </td></tr>
                <tr><td><asp:RadioButton ID="op3" runat="server" OnCheckedChange="check_Answer"/></td><td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer3") %> </td></tr>
                <tr><td><asp:RadioButton ID="op4" runat="server" OnCheckedChange="check_Answer"/></td><td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer4") %> </td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

In Code Behind

```
protected void check_Answer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = (sender as RadioButton).Parent as RepeaterItem;
        HiddenField hiddenField = item.FindControl("hiddenField") as HiddenField;

        String questionId = hiddenField.Value;
        Session["test"] = questionId;/*Just added to a session and passed to test page*/
        Response.Redirect("test.aspx");/*This Page Displays the value of Session["test"]*/
    }
```

Now what I need to do is OnCheckedChange event for the radio buttons  it calls a code behind method, but should pass the QuestionID value to the method. Please suggest me a way to retrieve the  value which contains the "QuestionID". For More Information the real interface looks like below,
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can group option buttons and use questionid as a part of group name. In the code you can get the questionid from GroupName. So you don't really need any hidden field. Your markup may look like below:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionId") %> </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Question") %> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer1") %>' 
                                OnCheckedChanged="check_Answer" GroupName='<%# Eval("QuestionId","Grp_{0}") %>'  />                       
                        </td>
                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer2") %>'  
                            OnCheckedChanged="check_Answer" GroupName='<%# Eval("QuestionId","Grp_{0}") %>'  />                        
                        </td>
                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer3") %>'  
                            OnCheckedChanged="check_Answer" GroupName='<%# Eval("QuestionId","Grp_{0}") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer4") %>'  
                            OnCheckedChanged="check_Answer" GroupName='<%# Eval("QuestionId","Grp_{0}") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in the code:

```
protected void check_Answer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string grpId = ((RadioButton)sender).GroupName;
    string  questionId = grpId.Split('_')[1].ToString();

    Session["test"] = questionId;/*Just added to a session and passed to test page*/
    Response.Redirect("test.aspx");/*This Page Displays the value of Session["test"]*/
}
```

Comment: This also works fine Afzalulh, but even in this case as i mentioned in above answer, it pass the lower QuestionID again whenever after checking an option from a lower QuestionID for Ex: IT001 and trying to check an option from a higher QuestionID ex: IT002, it passes IT001 always, but higher to lower it works fine

Comment: Did you change the markup also? In my test it is always working!

Comment: Yes, i changed them all but still when you start checking from IT001 onward, it always passes IT001, but from IT003 downward it works fine

Comment: Then there must be something in your code that is not compatible with our logic. You may send your code to look at.

Comment: Sent a mail to you afzalulh, including front end and code behind for this segment

Answer (score 1):

I would add hidden field as below

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionId") %>' runat="server" />
```

in your `check_Answer` event

```
RepeaterItem item = (sender as RadioButton).Parent as RepeaterItem;
HiddenField hiddenField = item.FindControl("hiddenField") as HiddenField;

string questionId= hiddenField.Value;
```

Comment: Hello Damith, thanx alot for the quick reply, your code works, but i guess due to some mistake of my code after checking 2 or 3 options from different rows, it tends to pass the same checked value from an old row. Do you see any wrong with that?

Comment: I tried even by changing "sender as Checkbox" to "sender as RadioButton"

Comment: Ok I found a clue, this happens whenever after checking an option from a lower QuestionID for Ex: IT001 and trying to check an option from a higher QuestionID ex: IT002, it returns IT001 always, but higher to lower it works fine